# "Speed limits are not available for this project" Issue when implementing the Google Speed Limit Api

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement google speed limit API to calculate the minimum speed required to travel from one location to other. But I am getting the below error when I run in the browser.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue? Thanks

```
"error": 
 {
 "code": 403,
 "message": "Speed limits are not available for this project.",
 "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Google, the Speed Limit service is only available to Google Maps **APIs Premium Plan Client.** 
This is not an issue with the Google Maps Web Services client library, rather it is an access issue with your API project. If you are an already Premium client, you can contact file a ticket in the Premium Plan support portal to enable the Google Maps Roads API.

Read the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits)

Comment: OK.. Do we need to pay to google cloud platform console inorder to be a premium plan customer...if that is the case any idea how much  do we need to pay?

Comment: Read the [Pricing and Billing Changes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/usage-and-billing)

Comment: I have already spoken to google support..then i got to know that, we need to have billing account...and also need to pay 7 lakhs...Do we need to pay that much amount to be a premium planned customer.